# Default value not visible in PdfTextFormField

Tags: itext7

I am using the code:

```
textfield.setValue(params.defval);
```

to set a default value for a PdfTextFormField. When the default value is not Latin characters (e.g. Hebrew or Russian) it only appears when the field has focus. For Latin text it appears always. Any assistance in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just setting the value isn't sufficient, did you also define a font that supports the other characters. Also: if you want support for Hebrew, Arabic, Devanagari, Kannada, Tamil, Telugu,... you will need iText 7.

Comment: The default does appear when clicking on the field, so I don't think there is a problem with the font.

Comment: When you click the field, the appearance is created by the PDF viewer. Before you click the field, the appearance that was created by iText is shown. If you don't provide a font to iText, the appearance can't be created correctly.

Comment: Interesting - I put "UTF-8" as the encoding in the createFont() method, and now it works.

Comment: Aha, so it was a font issue after all. More specifically: an encoding issue.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't understand why the text DID show when the field was clicked.

Comment: I repeat: *When you click the field, the appearance is created by the PDF viewer. Before you click the field, the appearance that was created by iText is shown. If you don't provide a font to iText, the appearance can't be created correctly.* Please explain if you either overlooked this comment, or if you didn't understand the difference between a dynamically created appearance and a static, pre-created appearance.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved. But please create an actual answer (David or @Bruno) for David to accept.

Comment: @mkl I think David is best placed to show how he solved the problem. If he posts an answer; I'll up-vote it.